# Defining default SIM for outgoing calls?

Tags: iphone

On my iPhone 14Pro, there is an eSIM (primary).

I now put in another, physical SIM (secondary).

How can I change ALL contacts to use secondary SIM when making calls to them?

All contact seems mixing up the SIMs: some tends to use "last used", which is obviously primary. Some forced to use primary, and it seems I can change this setting only 1-by-1.

Any tips?